# Scala: type mismatch issue with type Any and templated class

Tags: templates, scala

I have the following problem with the scala type system and I have currently no idea how to fix this.

Basically there is the follow situation:

I have a class, lets call it Actor. This class is templated.

```
class Actor[T](){
    def setValue(value: T): Int = {
        //do something with value
    }
}
```

Another class has a method which iterates over a HashMap of the following type:

```
var newValues = new HashMap[String, Any]()
```

This HashMap will contain values of type Int and String. The Key of the HashMap identifies a concrete Actor class and ensures that the type of the value fits the templated Actor class it refers to.

A method of the other class iterates over this HashMap:

```
newValues.foreach(
    kv => {
        db.getActor(kv._1).setValue(kv._2) //db.getActor returns an Actor identified by kv._1
    }
)
```

Because the concrete value (kv._2) has the same datatype like the templated class has recieved during runtime, I thought the scala engine would be able to cast the any-type into its concrete subtype T.

But I get the following error during compilation:

```
found   : kv._2.type (with underlying type Any)
required: _$3 where type _$3
   db.getActor(kv._1).setValue(kv._2)
```

Does anybody know to fix this problem? I thought by using the super-type Any it would be possible to get around a switch-case and using asInstanceOf[T] of object Any.

Hope somebody can help me!

Comment: You mean: your class `Actor` is a **generic** class, not a "templated" class. Note that templates like in C++ are not the same as generics in a language like Scala. (Generics may look like templates superficially but work in a completely different way).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is:

> Because the concrete value (kv._2) has
>   the same datatype like the templated
>   class has recieved during runtime,

Says who?

The compiler couldn't prove, at compile time, that this is, indeed, true. And, basically, it doesn't trust you.

You can always use `asIntanceOf` to tell the compiler that you know better -- also known as aiming a gun at your foot. And I wonder what type `db.getActor` returns! I'm half-guessing existential.